# What is a best design to hold a “global” mutable list?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, static

Let's say that I have an ArrayList of class Person and I have two objects that are generated from two different classes which read and write to this ArrayList.

For example,

```java
public class Main { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
       A a = new A();
       B b = new B();
   }
}
```

What, in your opinion is the best design to handle this ArrayList. I can think about two options:

1. create the Array List in class Main:

   ```java
   public class Main { 
      public static ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();

      public static void main(String[] args) { 
          A a = new A();
          B b = new B();
      }
   }
   ```

   and then access the list inside classes A and B via `Main.list`.
2. Create the ArrayList as a local variable in main method and send to the constructor of A and B.

   ```java
   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
           A a = new A(list);
           B b = new B(list);
       }
   }

   public class A { 
       private ArrayList<Person> list;
       public A(ArrayList<Person> list) { 
          this.list = list;
       }
   }
   ```

   and then list is an attribute of objects A and B.

Comment: None of them. Try this: A loops in the array list. Meanwhile, B adds, removes or modify entries. In these cases, you want a single access point for the list.

Comment: Can you show a small code example?

Comment: @Laiv Not necessarily. First, there is an issue only if a and b access the list from separate threads. Second, since this is not language-specific ArrayList *could* be a thread-safe container.

Comment: By the syntaxis, I assumed it was Java. In Java, (I think) ArrayList are not thread safe. On the other hand, if the ArrayList is a global resource, nothing is preventing you from accessing the list from different threads.

Comment: @Rado, how can you guarantee, that this publicly accessible list is only accessed by classes you know of?

Comment: @basilevs, as opposed to which other classes? Anyway, I did not advocate using globals. All i said was that one must not be concerned of multi threading problems until multiple threads are required.

Comment: @rado, any non-trivial program contains classes you don't know, you might forget some of yours or a complicated library does some nasty reflections in background, etc. The ads are already there in most modern languages, even if you did not want them. For example, garbage collection tends to do things in separate thread. Your suggestion would only hold for C and other  languages with same level of control.

Comment: Note: your option 2 is an example of a common design pattern, called Dependency Injection.

Comment: @basilevs, so all those libraries are just trying to get their hands on your global object FooBar? Cite the case when that ever happened to you. Again, not advocating the use of globals, but the reason that you have to worry about some other code unbeknown to you, looking to mess with your globals is just not a realistic one.

Comment: @Basilevs You are expected to know the classes you are collaborating with and nothing more. If `A` and `B` are not asking for a thread-safe object in their interface then it is not your responsibility to provide them with a thread-safe object. If `A` or `B` want a thread-safe object it is their responsibility to ask for it in their interface.

Comment: How, can I know or provide any guarantees for classes accessing public static field?

Comment: Yes, this happened in my projects, when team had unexperienced developers. They tend to provide API to modify global state without even thinking about threading, encapsulation, or dependency management. Various components then.use it and get hard to reproduce,  but very nasty bugs.

Comment: @Basilevs You can't if you have global mutable state. Sorry, it looks like that's what you wanted to convey and I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With option 1 your list is actually global mutable state which is usually regarded as a Bad Thing. Passing dependencies to constructors as you do in option 2 is the right thing to do.

There could be issues with your option 2 like concurrency as mentioned by Laiv in a comment, `main` could not be the best place for this code or you might want to use factories to instantiate A or B to name a few, but you didn't provide enough context to assess these potential problems. As it is written, option 2 looks fine to me.

Comment: The problem with solution 2 is that if someone reads the code of class A, he/she may think mistakenly that only class A may affect the content of the list (only if the reader pays attention to the constructor, he/she may figure out that it's a dependency injection).

Solution 2 is also a global state, since the list is placed in the "area" of class Main, and classes A and B only look at it.

Solution 1, however, clarifies that the list is a global state, and whenever I see such a solution, it's very clear that the list content is not affected only by class A.

Comment: @CrazySynthax That would be an incorrect assumption since the list is not private to A, but comes in as a parameter. The 2nd option is preferable since it clearly states the dependencies of your classes and makes them testable.

Comment: Why? If we use solution 2, then class 'A' may have a private variable ArrayList<Person> and its constructor will assign the "global" state to the private variable (see edited post).

Comment: Because the A' private attribute is just a reference to the very same ArrayList in B. This is what we know as parameters by reference (opposite to parameters by value). The private's A list is not a copy. It's always the same list.

Comment: @CrazySynthax You are not responsible for other people making unjustified assumptions. And no, the `list` declared inside `Main.main` in option 2 is not global state. As you correctly stated in your question it is a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this handled with a read lock and a write lock. When a write lock is held by one thread, the read lock cannot be obtained by any thread, and no other thread may obtain the write lock. When one thread holds the read lock, other threads may also get the read lock, but no thread may get the write lock. The data can only be mutated when one thread holds the write lock (and by design no threads hold a read lock). This ensures that nobody mutates the data while it is being read. Also, in this scenario, there was only a single thread that was ever able to obtain the write lock. (It was the main UI thread because the data was mutated by the user making changes to the UI.) A similar architecture might work for your scenario.